# Referencing multiple different "HTTP Request Defaults" config elements multiple times in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm building load test plans and am new to JMeter myself.

Our system consists of 11 different microservices which all work as part of a application network. This means that there is a requirement for the test plans to repeatedly swap between requests to different host names, and authentication credentials, within the same text execution.

*So, my question is, is there any way in JMeter to declare (for example) "HTTP Request Defaults" config elements in a single location, that can then be referenced at-will by requests later on?*

I need these configuration elements to be declared in one single location to avoid a lot of duplication throughout all the test plans we need to build; and so they can be easily changed when our apps all change host names or credentials (e.g. changing between environments). I have been able to ease some of the pain by using *variables*, but it still leaves a lot of repetition.

I understand how something similar can be done with the HTTP requests themselves using Module Controller and Test Fragments; but the same doesn't work with the scoping of the config elements...
I understand that the following screenshot **doesn't** work, but I'm including it just to give you an idea of what I'm aiming for:

[image: image description]

Maybe it's just my naivety after coming from the ReadyAPI world (where you would first create the reusable request definition and later reference it..), but I would love to know if such a similar thing is possible in JMeter? And if not, I'd be glad to confirm that I'm not missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Many Thanks,

---

Edit: Still no luck with everything I've tried..